# Why `overflow: hidden` On `html` To Move The Scrolling Box To The Body?

Tags: html, css

I just stumbled across this use of `overflow: hidden` on `html` which doesn't seem logical to me:

```css
* {
  all: unset;
  display: revert;
}
html {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
}
body {
  height: 50vh;
  font-size: 5rem;
  background: white;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

It's about moving the scroll box from `html` to `body`, but I don't understand why this example only works with `overflow: hidden`?  The `body` is already only `50vh` in height, so there should no overflow occur on the `html` element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow-propagation):

> However, when the root element is an [HTML] html element (including XML syntax for HTML) **whose overflow value is visible** (in both axes), and that element has as a child a body element whose display value is also not none, user agents must instead apply the overflow-* values of the first such child element to the viewport. The element from which the value is propagated must then have a used overflow value of visible.

Setting overflow on the `html` will disable the propagation and keep the overflow on the body element

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I can accept it in 5 minutes!  I just don't understand the bit in the specification about "the element from which the value is propagated must then have a used overflow value of visible", this is not true for `body` in my case, what does that mean?

Comment: @fweth in your case it's not true but if you omit the overflow from the html, the value from body will get propagated and body will be "the element from which the value is propagated" and will have a value of overflow equal to visible (the initial value)